The maximum of $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_{\sigma(k)}a_{\sigma(k+1)}$ for $\sigma\in S_n$.
I have interest of the area of radar chart for given data.
The area depends on the order of data, so there is some order the area is maximum.
I want to know the order.
For mathematical argument, I simplify the situation. Let $a_1,\dots,a_n\in [0,1]$
such that $0\le a_1\le \cdots \le a_n\le 1$ and $\sigma\in S_n$ is a permutation.
Then,
$z_k:=a_{\sigma(k)}e^{\frac{2ki\pi}{n}}\in \mathbb{C}$. Then, $z_1,\dots,z_n$ make $n$-polygon and
the area $S=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \sin(\frac{2\pi}{n})a_{\sigma(k)}a_{\sigma(k+1)}$ where $a_{\sigma(0)}:=a_{\sigma(n)}$.
Thus, we want to know the maximum of $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_{\sigma(k)}a_{\sigma(k+1)}$ for $\sigma\in S_n$.
This problem implies when $n\ge 4$ since when $n=3$ the area is constant for $\sigma\in S_3$.
I also have interest to minimum problem.
